# UWP release build crashes but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, win-universal-app

The app Works perfectly fine when I deploy it from VS 2015 (Windows 10)
But the story is very different when I create the build from "Store > Create App Packages...", then install the app from the app from the powershell script.

I have isolated the problem to a section where I set an image for the lock screen. Whenever I click yes on the message dialog to change the lock screen I get a crash, I have attached the debugger and I only get the following exception:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFA61091F08 (KernelBase.dll) in 
ApplicationFrameHost.exe: 0x80010012: 
The callee (server [not server application]) is not available 
and disappeared; all connections are invalid. The call did not execute.
```

The code to reproduce the error is based on the following article:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetlockscreenimageasync

```
    public async Task<bool> ChangeLockScreenBackground()
    {
        bool success = false;
        if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
        {
            var uri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/SplashScreen.scale-400.png");
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
            UserProfilePersonalizationSettings profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;
            success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file);
        }
        return success;


    }
```

I have no idea what is going on, I thought it was the capabilities of the app. 
But I have enabled User Account Information and Pictures Library and still no luck :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks that you're using a file already opened: SplashScreen* and also from that folder may be you can't set the wallpaper.

**Pay Attention**: "Your app can't set wallpapers from any folder. Copy file in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` and set wallpaper from there"

So I have changed the code a Little bit and also I put attention to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.system.userprofile.userprofilepersonalizationsettings.trysetlockscreenimageasync?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

> ***Remarks***
>
> *Caution   For the mobile device family, you can only set a lock screen image that is **smaller than 2 megabytes** (MB). Attempting to set
>   a lock screen image that is larger fails, even though the async
>   operation returns true.*
>   *Caution  **When you set an image more than once**, the new image file **must have a different name** than the previously set image. If you set a
>   new image using a file with the same name as the previous image, it
>   will fail.*

In this code I'm adding a file to Visual Studio Project in a folder called img, and setting the image properties to "Copy if newer". Then I load the image from such location.

```
async Task<bool> SetWallpaperAsync(string localAppDataFileName)
{
    bool success = false;
    var uri = new Uri($"ms-appx:///img/{localAppDataFileName}");

    //generate new file name to avoid colitions
    var newFileName = $"{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}{Path.GetExtension(localAppDataFileName)}";

    if (UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.IsSupported())
    {
        var profileSettings = UserProfilePersonalizationSettings.Current;

        var wfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);

        //Copy the file to Current.LocalFolder because TrySetLockScreenImageAsync
        //Will fail if the image isn't located there 
        using (Stream readStream = await wfile.OpenStreamForReadAsync(),
                      writestream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(newFileName,
                                     CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName)
              )
        { await readStream.CopyToAsync(writestream); }

        StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(newFileName);
        success = await profileSettings.TrySetLockScreenImageAsync(file);
    }

    Debug.WriteLine(success);
    return success;
}
```

This code works perfectly in Windows Mobile 10, and because this is an Universal App you should expect it runs same way in Windows 10 Apps... and yes.

Letme know if this was enough for you.

Comment: wtf!! same error? Where does it fail? Do you have a complete solution that I can review?

Comment: I'm uploading your solution to Github so you can compile it and see how it crashes. Only your code

Comment: Lol now it seems to work...  in a clean install  https://github.com/brusMX/Change-Lock-Screen-Background-Windows-10-

Comment: Man you have SAVED MY LIFE, the code is not really the problema the thing is that exactly. You cannot use a name of a file that you are using in runtime before

Comment: the code could not crash, but if you don't load the image for the correct folder the lockscreen won't be changed

Comment: It does crash if you choose the same file used for the splash

Comment: I know, but you should review if lookscreen is successfully set when imagefile is not in `Current.LocalFolder`